# Как поправить z-index при transform: rotate

Tags: css

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, проблема при меньшем разрешении, как это можно побороть? Вот снимок экрана с проблемой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня вроде бы вот с таким костылем заработало:

[image: Костыль]

2й вариант (правильный):

```
.wrap_location_input { z-index: 13; }
.wrap_categories_input {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
    z-index: 2;
    transform-style: flat;
}
```

Comment: Да, но теперь я не могу на инпут нажать)

Comment: И это срабатывает если блок relative, я убираю relative и могу нажать на блок но он опять не перекрывает

Comment: Попробуй второй вариант.

Comment: Да, всё отлично, спасибо большое) Вы сами тыкали или в гугле нашли? Просто я такого решения не нашел

Comment: Первое сам натыкал, второе нашел ;)

Comment: Да уж) Искать надо уметь)